# Miss- prefix verbs: which have infinitives that act like they are separable?

Tags: verb

I've recently come across some verbs with 'miss' as a prefix, are inseparable, but act as if they are separable in an infinitive clause e.g. 'misszuverstehen'. I believe this is the most popular infinitive form of 'missverstehen'. Could somebody please clarify which other 'miss'  verbs this is possible with and how common it is compared to the alternative? 
For example: which is more widely seen; 'misszutrauen' or 'zu misstrauen'?

Comment: The list of exceptions of "miss-" verbs that behave partially like a separable and partially like an inseparable verb is short and easy - *missverstehen* is the one, *missleiten* the other.

Comment: Misstrauen kenne ich, aber missvertrauen, gar misszuvertrauen? Zu misstrauen ist mechanischen Operationen am offenen Sprachkörper.

Comment: @tofro thanks for your reply. I have read in a grammar book that it is also used with misstrauen and some others, but less commonly. Would you agree with this?

Comment: @tofro add "missinterpretieren"

Comment: @Uwe Duden says the two I mentioned are the only ones.

Comment: @Uwe Possibly native speakers sometimes don't recognise the rule themselves and so say things like 'misszuinterpretieren' even though it's not officialy grammatically correct. This could account for the 'less common' usage described in my book, perhaps?

Comment: @Jamie There is no authority (Duden or otherwise) that declares what's "officially grammatically correct". Grammatical rules *describe* what (most) native speakers consider as correct, they don't *prescribe* what's correct. As the usage of  native speakers changes, so do the rules. With "missinterpretieren" both forms are used. Currently, for the infinitive, "zu missinterpretieren" seems to be more common than "misszuinterpretieren", but for the gerundive, "misszuinterpretierende" seems to be more common than "zu missinterpretierende".

Comment: @tofro: Ich zitiere [www.duden.de](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Verben-mit-der-Vorsilbe-miss): "Wenn miss- jedoch ausnahmsweise (nach dem Muster von „maßregeln“) den Hauptton trägt, dann werden das Partizip II und der Infinitiv mit „zu“ wie folgt gebildet:
missgeleitet – misszuleiten; missverstanden – misszuverstehen." Da bei "missinterpretieren" der Hauptton auf der Vorsilbe "miss-" liegt, folgt daras was?

Comment: @Uwe Wie kommst du darauf, dass "der Hauptton bei miss- liegt"? Ich hör' nix.

Comment: @tofro Ich betone "missinterpretieren" auf der ersten Silbe, und der Duden stimmt mir da zu https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/missinterpretieren, auch wenn er andererseits als Infinitiv "zu missinterpretieren" angibt.

Answer (score 4):

The basic rule is:

- If the verb prefix *"miss-"* is unstressed, it behaves
  like other inseparable prefixes: In the infinitive, *"zu"* is
  put in front (*"misslingen" → "zu misslingen"*);
  in the past participle, *"ge-"* is dropped
  (*"misslingen" → "misslungen"*).
- If *"miss-"* is stressed,
  it behaves partially like a separable prefix:
  In the infinitive, *"zu"* is put between *"miss-"* and the rest of
  the verb
  (*"missverstehen" → "misszuverstehen"*);
  in the past participle, *"ge-"* is put between *"miss-"* and the rest of
  the verb if there is no further prefix
  (*"missleiten → "missgeleitet"*, but
  *"missverstehen" → "missverstanden"*).

Currently, there seems to be only one verb for which all native
speakers agree that the stress is on *"miss-"*, namely *"missverstehen"*.
There are three more verbs in which *"miss-"* is sometimes stressed
and sometimes not, namely *"missdeuten"*, *"missleiten"*, and
*"missinterpretieren"*, and consequently, you
will find both variants for these verbs,
say, *"zu missDEUten"* and *"MISSzudeuten"*.
(In particular, there seems to be a preference for "MISSzu-"
in gerundives, such as "MISSzudeutende".)

Note, however, that stress patterns are subject to change.
Two hundred years ago, *"missachten"* was still stressed on the first
syllable (so Goethe wrote *"misszuachten"*, or rather *"mißzuachten"*);
and [Heyse's school grammar from 1830](https://books.google.de/books?id=hdRIAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA180&ots=2wXZdLQ3Rh&dq=%22Eben%20so%20ruhet%20auch%20der%20Ton%20in%20den%20mit%20miss%20zusammengesetzten%20Meldew%C3%B6rtern%22&hl=de&pg=PA181#v=onepage&q=%22Eben%20so%20ruhet%20auch%20der%20Ton%20in%20den%20mit%20miss%20zusammengesetzten%20Meldew%C3%B6rtern%22&f=false)
distingished between
*"MISShandeln"* (*"to sin"*), hence *"misszuhandeln"*,
and
*"missHANdeln"* (*"to treat someone badly"*), hence *"zu misshandeln"*.

Comment: Danke, dass du meinen Einwand berücksichtigt hast! Selbst der Duden scheint sich bei *missinterpretieren* nicht sicher zu sein, andere Wörterbücher gehen auf diesen Sonderfall gar nicht ein.

Comment: @tofro Bei "missdeuten" sieht's genauso aus: Betonung laut Duden auf der ersten Silbe, trotzdem wird "zu missdeuten" angegeben.